# How does getHeight recursively determine the height of a binary tree?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I'm really not understanding the logic behind the code to compute the height of a binary tree. If someone understands it, can you explain it in a simple way?

I tried understanding by placing break points, but still the logic is unclear to me.

```
import pdb
class Node:
  def __init__(self,data):
      self.right=self.left=None
      self.data = data
      #print(self.data)
class Solution:  #creating and inserting the nodes
  def insert(self,root,data):
      #print(data)
      if root==None:
         return Node(data)
      else:
         if data<=root.data:
             cur=self.insert(root.left,data)
             root.left=cur
         else:
             cur=self.insert(root.right,data)
             root.right=cur
      return root
  def getHeight(self,root): #finding the height of the largest 
                               branchintree
    #Write your code here
    if not root:
        return -1
    if not root.left and not root.right:
        return 0
    left_height=self.getHeight(root.left)
    #print('left_height',left_height)
    right_height=self.getHeight(root.right)
    #print('right_height',right_height)
    r=max(left_height,right_height) + 1
    #print('r',r)
    return max(left_height,right_height) + 1




T=int(input())
pdb.set_trace()
myTree=Solution()
root=None
for i in range(T):
   data=int(input())
   root=myTree.insert(root,data)
height=myTree.getHeight(root)
print(height)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Note that the algorithm for finding the height of a tree is the same for binary search trees as well as general binary trees, so I will ignore BSTs for the purposes of this discussion.*</sup>

---

This code is not particularly clear, so I don't blame you for not understanding it.

Here's a re-write to cut through the noise:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Node = namedtuple("Node", "data left right")

def height(root): 
    return max(height(root.left), height(root.right)) + 1 if root else 0
    #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^         ^^^^^^     
    #      |                                          |           |
    #      |                                          |           base case; root is None
    #      |                                          add the current node's height
    #      recursively find the maximum height of the current node's children


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """     1 
          /   \
         2     3
          \    /
           4  5
               \
                6 
    """
    root = Node(
        1,
        Node(
            2,
            None,
            Node(4, None, None)
        ),
        Node(
            3,
            Node(
                5,
                None,
                Node(6, None, None)
            ),
            None
        )
    )
    print(height(root)) # => 4
```

Now, we have two cases in a given call to `height`:

- `root` is `None`, in which case we return 0 because we have nothing. This is our *base case*, or condition that terminates the recursion.
- `root` is not `None`, in which case we return 1 to count the height of the current node under consideration by this particular recursive call *plus* the maximum of the height of the left and right subtrees rooted at the current node. 
  This is the critical recursive step.

Let's walk through a call to `height` on the above example tree.

We first visit node `{1}` as our root. This isn't a base case, so `{1}` asks its left child `{2}` for its maximum height. `{2}` isn't a base case either, so it asks its left child, `None`, for its total. `None` is our first base case and returns 0 back to `{2}`. `{2}` then asks for the height of its right child, `{4}`. `{4}` is a leaf with two empty `None` references which return 0, but `{4}` adds 1 for itself and returns this to `{2}`.

Node `{2}` can now compute `max(height(root.left), height(root.right))` which is `max(0, 1) => 1`, and `{2}` can add 1 to count its own height and report back to `{1}` its total of 2.

Our root `{1}` now has a height of 2 for its left subtree, but it hasn't checked its right subtree yet, so `max(height(root.left), height(root.right))` has to wait.

The process is basically the same for the right subtree of `{1}`: if the node isn't a leaf node, it asks its children for their respective heights and takes the max, adding 1 to count itself, and reporting to the parent. In this case, `{6}` reports a height of 1 to `{5}`, `{5}` reports a height of 2 to `{3}` and `{3}` reports a height of 3 to `{1}`. At long last, `{1}` can compute `max(2, 3)` and add 1 for its own height, returning the final result of 4 to the caller.

If all of this is a bit abstract, you can always tool the recursive call to add a `depth` parameter and print its status.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Node = namedtuple("Node", "data left right")

def height(root, depth=0): 
    if root:
        print(" " * depth + f"{{{root.data}}} asking children...")
        left_height = height(root.left, depth + 4)
        right_height = height(root.right, depth + 4)
        ret = max(left_height, right_height) + 1
        print(" " * depth + f"{{{root.data}}} reporting max({left_height}, {right_height}) + 1 = {ret}")
        return ret

    print(" " * depth + "None returning 0")
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """     1 
          /   \
         2     3
          \    /
           4  5
               \
                6 
    """
    root = Node(
        1,
        Node(
            2,
            None,
            Node(4, None, None)
        ),
        Node(
            3,
            Node(
                5,
                None,
                Node(6, None, None)
            ),
            None
        )
    )
    print(height(root)) # => 4
```

Output:

```
{1} asking children...
    {2} asking children...
        None returning 0
        {4} asking children...
            None returning 0
            None returning 0
        {4} reporting max(0, 0) + 1 = 1
    {2} reporting max(0, 1) + 1 = 2
    {3} asking children...
        {5} asking children...
            None returning 0
            {6} asking children...
                None returning 0
                None returning 0
            {6} reporting max(0, 0) + 1 = 1
        {5} reporting max(0, 1) + 1 = 2
        None returning 0
    {3} reporting max(2, 0) + 1 = 3
{1} reporting max(2, 3) + 1 = 4
4
```